# Blog double login

Tags: bug, status-completed, blog

Since the change of domain, we have the particular problem of having to log in twice to blog.

In fact, the address of the admin site is : http://gaming.blogoverflow.com/ while the preview module redirects to http://blog.gaming.stackexchange.com/

Hence the cookie is not recognised on the second domain and force us to relog using that particular domain to set up a second cookie.

Can someone look at the admin of the wordpress to solve this by :

- Changing the cookie scope if possible
- Migrating all to the same domain

This double login is also messing up our ability to properly preview posts.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There was a pesky little check box in the network setup that said "Redirect administration pages to site's original domain (remote login disabled if this redirect is disabled)". It has been unchecked.

Comment: Thank you so much! So glad this is finally fixed. :D

Comment: /Blame @rebecca she just pointed it out to me yesterday :)